# How to tokenize a paragraph which have numbered list into multiple sentences using python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm planning to break the paragraph into multiple sentences. This paragraph contains numbered sentences like shown below:

```
Hello, How are you? Hope everything is good. I'm fine. 1.Hello World. 2.Good Morning John. 

Product is good but the managemnt is very lazy very bad. I dont like company service. They are giving fake promises. Next time i will not take any product. For Amazon service i will give 5 star dey give awsome service. But for sony company i will give 0 star... 1. Doesn't support all file formats when you connect USB 2. No other apps than YouTube and Netflix (requires subscription) 3. Screen mirroring is not up to the mark ( getting connected after once in 10 attempts 4. Good screen quality 5. Audio is very good 6. Bulky compared to other similar range 7. Price bit high due to brand value 8. its 1/4 smart TV. Not a full smart TV 9. Bad customer support 10. Remote control is very horrible to operate. it might be good for non smart TV 11. See the exchange value on amazon itself. LG gets 2ooo/- more than TV's 12. Also it was mentioned like 1+1 year warranty. But either support or Amazon support aren't clear about it. 13. Product information isn't up to 30% at least.There no installation. While I contact costumer Care.
```

I had used the below code to break into sentences:

```
import nltk
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer()
fp = open("/Users/Desktop/sample.txt", encoding='utf-8')
data = fp.read()
with open("/Users/Desktop/output.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8' ) as f:
            f.write(''.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data)))
            f.close()
```

This code is splitting the paragraph based on full stops. But the numbered sentence are creating an issue. Since these have fullstops after numbers, it is splitting in an improper manner.

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same?

Comment: Yes. I have tried using sent_tokenize. I'm able to split the paragraph into sentences. But, still facing issue for the numbered lists.

Comment: It's working fine with `sent_tokenize`. See my answer.

Comment: For the 1st paragraph, it splitted properly but not  for the 2nd paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You need `sent_tokenize`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

text = "Hello, How are you? Hope everything is good. I'm fine. 1.Hello World. 2.Good Morning John."

print(sent_tokenize(text))
```

*output*

```
['Hello, How are you?', 'Hope everything is good.', "I'm fine.", '1.Hello World.', '2.Good Morning John.']
```

Comment: I have edited one more paragraph in my query. For this particular paragraph, it is unable to split

Answer (score 0):

@AkshayNevrekar @fervent sent_tokenize uses by default PunktSentenceTokenizer so you should have same results. https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

> nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text, language='english')[source]¶
>      Return a sentence-tokenized copy of text, using NLTK’s recommended sentence  tokenizer (currently PunktSentenceTokenizer for the specified language).

Maybe you two have differents versions of NLTK ?

According to https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer

> This tokenizer divides a text into a list of sentences
>   by using an unsupervised algorithm to build a model for abbreviation
>   words, collocations, and words that start sentences.  It must be
>   trained on a large collection of plaintext in the target language
>   before it can be used.
>
> The NLTK data package includes a pre-trained Punkt tokenizer for
>   English.

This module uses machine learning algorithms to cut your text. You use an already trained tokenizer. If you are not happy with the results, you need to train this tokenizer yourself with a collection of texts similar to the one you want to split. Splitting text in sentences is not an easy task and you probably wont be 100% happy with this kind of algorithms. You need to accept some mistakes as it is very hard to predict its behavior.

You can try to implement your own algorithm based on rules you define yourself. As an example (not perfect but you have the expected number of sentences):

```
import re
text = "Hello, How are you? Hope everything is good. I'm fine. 1.Hello World. 2.Good Morning John. Product is good but the managemnt is very lazy very bad. I dont like company service. They are giving fake promises. Next time i will not take any product. For Amazon service i will give 5 star dey give awsome service. But for sony company i will give 0 star... 1. Doesn't support all file formats when you connect USB 2. No other apps than YouTube and Netflix (requires subscription) 3. Screen mirroring is not up to the mark ( getting connected after once in 10 attempts 4. Good screen quality 5. Audio is very good 6. Bulky compared to other similar range 7. Price bit high due to brand value 8. its 1/4 smart TV. Not a full smart TV 9. Bad customer support 10. Remote control is very horrible to operate. it might be good for non smart TV 11. See the exchange value on amazon itself. LG gets 2ooo/- more than TV's 12. Also it was mentioned like 1+1 year warranty. But either support or Amazon support aren't clear about it. 13. Product information isn't up to 30% at least.There no installation. While I contact costumer Care."
print(list(re.findall('.*?[a-z].*?[0-9a-z][\?\.\!]+', text)))
```

It is easier to get predictable results with this kind of algorithms. But it will do poorly on unexpected texts because it is very hard to find rules that will work on any sentence.

To help you chose a solution :

- You know the inputs : try to do your own algorithm using rules, and add rules until you are happy with the result
- You will have unexpected inputs : NLTK algorithms will probably do better, but you cannot be certain of how it will split your text.